# Conflict between making a div a clickable link and vertical centering

Tags: html, css

To make the rounded boxes (see http://jsfiddle.net/L36nq/) clickable/hoverable, I need to use

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Yet to keep the images (the two squares) centered, I need to use

```
#left  {
    display:table;
    ...
}
#right {
    display:table;
    ...
}
```

How do I make the full rounded boxes clickable/hoverable while keeping the images centered?

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="cell">
        <a href="http://google.com/">
            <img src="box.svg" width="75%" height="75%" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <div id="cell">
        <a href="http://bing.com/">
            <img src="box.svg" width="75%" height="75%" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left  {
    display:table; position:absolute;
    top:25%; left:25%; width:24%; height:50%;
    vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; margin: auto; border-radius:30px;
    background-color: #D88;
}
#right {
    display:table; position:absolute;
    top:25%; left:51%; width:24%; height:50%;
    vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; margin: auto; border-radius:30px;
    background-color: #88D;
}
#cell {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}

a {
    display: block;
}

body { background-color: #9D9; }
```

Comment: Try Add `padding-top:2.5%;` in the right and left div style to make  SVGs centered. and add `a:hover { display: block; background:#f60; }` in your css file.

Comment: "Making the entire box clickable" being #cell or #left, #right?

Comment: @EdiSutrisno  I'm not sure: you're commenting that it doesn't look right (or symmetric?), but your suggestion does not solve the problem. Is that right?

Comment: @Torr3nt #left and #right would be ideal, but I'll settle for a solution for #cell alone.

Comment: Can you give us some live demo?

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
display: block;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
```

Your anchor tag is not inheriting and height or width so it's essentially 0x0 px. The above css worked for me in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MkfAe/

Comment: In http://jsfiddle.net/MkfAe/ you do make the rounded-corner boxes clickable, but the inner boxes are no longer centered.

Comment: Looks good.. but still this nasty problem of 1:1 ratio. The text fonts look rather terrible, not to mention the images themselves, if the <img>s are not kept at the same aspect ratio. It's best to include a square and confirm it continues to be a square. Html5-canvas, SVG, or a good-old png are all suitable to test this. It's not clear whether jsfiddle.net will let one use any of these.

Comment: I would use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pd5GT/
or write css queries and give the image a pixel height or width
EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/eJjgW/
I pasted the wrong fork link

Comment: In your first link the images do keep their aspect ratio. In the second they do keep their aspect ratio, but a subset of the images can become invisible. I am looking for a design that continues to look good whether the user is using a desktop or a portable device, especially when switching from portrait to landscape and back. How would you solve it?

Comment: Media queries. Setting min-height or width on the images as well as the containing cells. I don't know how to make it work for every existing pixel combination but would be fine for 99% of users. I'm not sure what the entire application is, so it's hard to say. There may be a way to get it to work perfectly but I don't have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/ZNXvT/1/

I'm taking your `#cell` elements and keeping them as block-level elements, and setting a `height: 100%;` on them. I also set `height: 100%;` on your anchor element.

```
#cell {
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now onto the magic. You can add an element inside the a (I called mine `.valign-height`) and set that as `height: 100%;`, and also add a `vertical-align: middle;`.

```
a .valign-height {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
}
```

Then with the image (or svg) itself, I set that to `vertical-align: middle;`.

```
a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

An element is not able to be vertically-aligned by itself, as vertical-align aligns to its siblings. If we have a hidden element that will spoof the vertical-align for you, it will center your content always. This way, you can keep the anchor filling the space, and keep your img element vertically centered.

Comment: All wonderful... but how can the aspect ratio of the two <img>s be preserved? The images/text within can be shrunk/magnified but cannot change aspect ratio.

Comment: Well, 75% height of the parent is going to be taller. You're physically setting the height there.

Comment: The idea from width="75%" height="75%" is to magnify/shrink the SVGs depending on the size of the display area. If I change the browser from skewed landscape to skewed portrait, the SVGs continue to be be magnified in a 1:1 ratio. How can this be maintained?

Comment: If they exist in a 1:1 ratio, you should only have to set the width.

Comment: Not exactly. Changing the dimensions of the Result section at http://jsfiddle.net/tGuqn/ shows that the two squares remain square, but that they occupy as much of their respective rounded-corner box to remain square.